# Trying to print an object with an array of object in it Html

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm trying to print this object:

```
export class Ricette {
    nome: string;
    azioni: {tempo: number, azione: string}[][]
  }
```

```
export const RICETTE : Ricette[] = [
    {
        nome: 'Alici',
        azioni: [[
            {tempo: 500, azione: 'scongela'},
            {tempo: 60, azione: 'nulla'}        
        ]]
    },
    {
        nome: 'Baccalà',
        azioni: [[
            {tempo: 500, azione: 'scongela'}],
            [
                {tempo: 210, azione: 'immerso'},
                {tempo: 210, azione: 'cestello su'},
                {tempo: 30, azione: 'immerso'}
            ]        
        ]
    },
    {
        nome: 'Hamburger',
        azioni: [[
            {tempo: 500, azione: 'scongela'}],
            [
                {tempo: 210, azione: 'immerso'},
                {tempo: 210, azione: 'cestello su'},
                {tempo: 30, azione: 'immerso'}
            ]        
        ]
    }
];
```

```
ricette = RICETTE;
```

in an html file.

the array `azioni[]` is going to have different length in every item of `ricette`.

what can I do for print the object in a html <'ul><'li><'/li><'/ul>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such type:

```
azioni: {tempo: number, azione: string}[]
```

But there is a such type and its name is `object`:

```
azioni: {tempo: number, azione: string}
```

You can use `*ngFor` to show the following format data:

```
ricetta : Ricette = {
    nome: 'Alici',
    azioni: [
      {tempo: 500, azione: 'scongela'},
      {tempo: 60, azione: 'nulla'}]
  }
```

and HTML:

```
div>
    <span>Nome-> </span>{{ricetta.nome}}
</div>
<ul *ngIf="ricetta?.azioni && ricetta?.azioni.length > 0">
    <li *ngFor="let item of ricetta?.azioni ; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
        {{item?.tempo}}
        {{item?.azione}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE:**
You can use the second loop:

```
<div *ngFor="let ricetta of ricettaArray">
            <h2>{{ricetta.nome}}:</h2>
            <div>
                <span>Nome-> </span>{{ricetta.nome}}</div>
                <ul *ngIf="ricetta && ricetta?.length > 0">
                    <li *ngFor="let item of ricetta?.azioni;">
                        {{item?.tempo}}
                        {{item?.azione}}

                        <p> The second loop: </p>
                        <ul>
                            <li *ngFor="let subItem of item"> 
                               {{subItem.tempo}} 
                               {{subItem.azione}}
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: thanks. I have edited my question. I have modified the object. can you please help Me?

Comment: @AndreaFavero Yeah, but there is no such type: `azioni: {tempo: number, azione: string}[]` ? What type do you want to use? and could you fill the sample data?

Comment: ```azioni[]``` is an array and inside it there is an array of object

Comment: I've included the full data in the question

Comment: @AndreaFavero I've updated my answer. Sorry, I've edited `bat7` answer and put my code to `bat7` answer, not my. I was very hurry. Sorry:). Could you reconsider my updated answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can add parent div with `*ngFor` in order to display all values of the array like following:

```
  <div *ngFor="let ricetta of ricettaArray">
        <h2>{{ricetta.nome}}:</h2>
        <div>
            <span>Nome-> </span>{{ricetta.nome}}</div>
            <ul *ngIf="ricetta?.azioni && ricetta?.azioni.length > 0">
                <li *ngFor="let item of ricetta?.azioni ; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
                    {{item?.tempo}}
                    {{item?.azione}}
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

the ricettaArray declaration looks as following:

```
 ricettaArray : Ricette[] = [];

  let r1 = {
      nome: 'Alici',
      azioni: [
        {tempo: 500, azione: 'scongela'},
        {tempo: 60, azione: 'nulla'}]
    };
    let r2 = {
      nome: 'Blici',
      azioni: [
        {tempo: 400, azione: 'bcongela'},
        {tempo: 50, azione: 'bulla'},
        {tempo: 500, azione: 'bulldsfa'}]
    };
    this.ricettaArray.push(r1);
    this.ricettaArray.push(r2);
```

Comment: it works pretty well, thanks.
can you edit the last part of the code?

Comment: @AndreaFavero Sorry I've inserted my answer to not right place. Sorry, bat7. Now I've updated my answer